# Differences between EasyMock and Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito, easymock

I'm learning testing with EasyMock and Mockito. What are differences between them?
What are advantages and disadvantages of any of them? Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although this question is majorly opinion based but you get the differences from [here](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock):

> **Differences**:
>
> - no record/replay modes - no need for them. There only 2 things you    can do with Mockito mocks - verify or stub. Stubbing goes before execution and verification afterwards.
> - all mocks are 'nice' (even somehow nicer, because    collection-returning methods return empty collections instead of nulls). Even though mocks are nice, you can verify them as strictly
>     as you want and detect any unwanted interaction.
> - explicit language for better readability: verify() and when() VS the    mixture of expect(mock.foo()) and mock.foo() (plain method call without 'expect'). I'm sure some of you will find this argument  subjective :)
> - simplified stubbing model - stubbed methods replay all the time with    stubbed value no matter how many times they are called. Works exactly    like EasyMock's andStubReturn(), andStubThrow(). Also, you can stub    with different return values for different arguments (like
>     in    EasyMock).
> - Verification of stubbed methods is optional because usually it's more    important to test if the stubbed value is used correctly rather than    where's it come from.
> - verification is explicit - verification errors point at line of code    showing what interaction failed. verification in order is flexible    and doesn't require to verify every single interaction.
> - custom argument matchers use hamcrest matchers, so you can use your    existing hamcrest matchers. (EasyMock can also integrate with  hamcrest though it is not a part of EasyMock but hamcrest. See the
>     documentation of hamcrest).